# python - convert csv to txt without losing column alignment

Tags: python, csv, text-files

I want to convert multiple csv files to txt using python without losing the column alignment.

An example of a csv file, which is comma delimited with no spaces or tabs,  appears as follows:

```
"Products" "Technologies" Region1 Region2 Region3
Prod1       Tech1         16      0       12
Prod2       Tech2         0       12      22
Prod3       Tech3         22      0       36
```

But using my script I end up with the following:

```
"Products" "Technologies" Region1 Region2 Region3
Prod1 Tech1 16 0 12
Prod2 Tech2 0 12 22
Prod3 Tech3 22 0 36
```

The selection of delimiter is arbitrary. Is there a relatively easy way to achieve what I want, taking into consideration that the tables withing the csv files will vary in dimension and the column headers will vary in length?

I use the following python code:

```
import os
import fileinput
dire = "directory"

# function for converting csv files to txt
def csv_to_txt(names, txtfilename):

    # remove existing txt file
    if os.path.exists(dire + txtfilename + ".txt"):
        os.remove(dire + txtfilename + ".txt")

    # open the include file
    includefile = open(dire + txtfilename + ".txt", "a")

    # handle the csv files and convert to txt
    with open(names, "a+") as input_file:
        lines = [line.split(",", 2) for line in input_file.readlines()]
        print lines
        text_list = [" ".join(line) for line in lines]

        for line in text_list:
            includefile.write(line)
    includefile.close()


csv_to_txt(dire + "01.csv", "nameofoutputfile")

for line in fileinput.FileInput(dire + "nameofoutputfile" + ".txt",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace('"','')
    line = line.replace(',',' ')
```

Comment: Sorry I can't see any difference between what you want and what you've got now.

Comment: Here, your actual and expected both the results are same. May be you typed something wrong

Comment: What code do you use to write your txt file?

Comment: Hi Allen and Chanda,
I updated the table so that you may see what I am referring to. Also, I added the code as requested by pingui.

Comment: if you open csv file (comma separated values) you will see values separated by coma, not spaces.

Comment: @WalidMustapha I have given it my best shot, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV files carry no formatting or alignment info, it is just data separated by comma. Normally it is table processor job to render csv pretty.

To read a file into list or dictionary use csv standard module. For best results in pretty printing use  PrettyTable or PTable fork https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable/0.9.0. Other tools are https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate or texttable https://oneau.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/simple-formatted-tables-in-python-with-texttable, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifultable/.

with PTable

```
   from prettytable import from_csv
   fp = open("myfile.csv", "r")
   mytable = from_csv(fp)
   fp.close()
   mytable.border = False
   print mytable.get_string()
```

For few simple tables a simple [snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578801-pretty-print-table-in-tabular-format) might do as well.

Personally, when I had to print out a table without extra hassle with packages I would use some ad-hoc string formatting, but packages usually more fool-proved, support many options, so if you gonna deal with many tables it might be worth the effort.

---

Prettytable seems be the most popular (great name).
Tabulate [claims](https://txt.arboreus.com/2013/03/13/pretty-print-tables-in-python.html) better performance than most pretty table printers, save asciitable ( now astropy.io.ascii , so might be a bit of overkill unless you are a rocket scientist )

Comment: Hi Serge,
Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Anytime, good luck. If you find the answer helpful do not hesitate to upvote or accept it

Answer (score 0):

I have made a program that opens a .csv and does (hopefully) exactly what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import csv as csv_package

def fileopen():
    GUI=tk.Tk()
    filepath=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=GUI,
                                        title='Select file')
    (GUI).destroy()
    return (filepath)

filepath = fileopen()
filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath)
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    reader = csv_package.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

#make spreadsheet rows consistent length, based on longest row
max_len_row = len(max(data,key=len))
for row in data:
    if len(row) < max_len_row:
        append_number = max_len_row - len(row)
        for i in range(append_number):
            row.append('')

#create dictionary of number of columns
longest = {}
for times in range(len(data[0])):
    longest [times] = 0

#get longest entry for each column
for sublist_index,sublist in enumerate(data):
    for column_index,element in enumerate(sublist):
        if longest [column_index] < len(element):
            longest [column_index] = len(element)

#make each column as long as the longest entry
for sublist_index,sublist in enumerate(data):
    for column_index,element in enumerate(sublist):
        if len(element) < longest [column_index]:
            amount_to_append = longest [column_index] - len(element)
            data [sublist_index][column_index] += (' ' * amount_to_append)

with open(filepath, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv_package.writer(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)

path, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
os.rename(filepath, path + '.txt')
```

before:

```
"Products","Technologies",Region1,Region2,Region3
Prod1,Tech1,16,0,12
Prod2,Tech2,0,12,22
Prod3,Tech3,22,0,36
```

after:

```
Products,Technologies,Region1,Region2,Region3
Prod1   ,Tech1       ,16     ,0      ,12     
Prod2   ,Tech2       ,0      ,12     ,22     
Prod3   ,Tech3       ,22     ,0      ,36
```

Comment: Hi new_to_coding,
Thank for for providing help here. I made this work also.